# Android Kotlin not able to get result from another activity

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, asynchronous, okhttp

I need to start an acivity from my main activity and this second activity has to do a REST call (I'm using OkHttp) and return the result to the main activity. I'm actually able to do all the process, but when I come back to the main activity I can't get the resulting data. Here's the code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            Log.d("Main", data.toString())
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
            resultLauncher.launch(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity)
            
        customFunction(this)
    }
    
    private fun customFunction(activity: Activity) {
        var json: String? = ""

        val payload = "custom payload"

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        val requestBody = payload.toRequestBody()
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Basic mytoken")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .url("myurl")
            .method("POST", requestBody)
            .build()

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.d("SecondActivity", "onFailure")
                activity.finish()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                json = response.body?.string()
                Log.d("SecondActivity", "$json")

                val data = Intent()
                data.putExtra("json", json)
                Log.d("SecondActivity", data.toString())
                activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
                activity.finish()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So, inside `customFunction()` I'm able to fetch that json and to put it in the data Intent. In fact, when I print it with `Log.d()` it says `Intent { (has extras) }` and so it's fine. But when I receive it in the MainActivity within `registerForActivityResult` it prints `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the extra of the `Intent` in the launcher activity of the `MainActivity` in this case i.e.

Instead of

```
var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            Log.d("Main", data.toString())
        }
```

Use

```
var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            val actualExtraData = data.getExtra("json") // Here is your actual data 
            Log.d("Main", data.toString())
        }
```

Comment: I tried with `val actualExtraData = data?.extras?.get("json")` and `Log.d("Main", actualExtraData .toString())` but still getting null

Comment: If I print `result` directly I get `ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}`

Comment: Maybe the response is not getting serialized properly then

Comment: How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

In `SecondActivity` you are using method `putExtra` and passing value `json` as String . So in MainActivity get it by

`val data = result.data?.getStringExtra("json")`

```
var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
       // val data: Intent? = result.data
        val data = result.data?.getStringExtra("json")
        Log.d("Main", data.toString())
    }
```

Comment: Still `null`. As said in the previous comment, if I print `result` directly I get `ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}`

Comment: json = response.body()?.string() check this line your method ,  is body? ok? or would body()?

Comment: If I print `json` in my second activity I can see the actual json object. So it meas the problem happens when I go back to the main activity. It seems like `setResult()` method is not working properly or isn't working at all.

Comment: Are you using android:launchMode singleTask or singleInstance , check your manifest file .

Comment: There is no `android:launchMode` in my manifest file

Comment: Add all the logs to your question as well so that maybe we can see as in the things you are logging to check